# Paradox vertical placement of pictures

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, luatex

I discovered some strange behaviour of (Lua)LaTeX. I have three eepic pictures fitting vertically aligned on the same page. Now if I slightly enlarge them horizontally (just to exhaust the `\textwidth` better), the third picture is made up to the next page. **Why is this happening?**

Here is a minimal working example:

```
%% LyX 2.2.2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
\documentclass[german]{article}
\usepackage[latin9]{luainputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3cm}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{bxeepic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eepicemu}

\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage} %Seitenumbruch für neues Kapitel

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{headings}

\section{See the frames}

Textwidth: \the\textwidth

\newpage{}
\begin{center}
\input{dummygraphic}


\input{dummygraphic}


\input{dummygraphic} 
\par\end{center}
\end{document}
```

This is the file `dummygraphic.tex`:

```
\setlength{\unitlength}{0.120000pt}
\begin{picture}(3200,1800)(0,0)
\thicklines \path(0,0)(3200,0)(3200,1800)(0,1800)(0,0)
\end{picture}
```

If I enlarge the picture by replacing `3200` by `3480`, I'm still below `\textwidth`, so the pictures still fit horizontally. However, vertically, nothing has been changed yet the last picture is moved to the next page.

Comment: For one, you can remove the blank lines (paragraph breaks) from between the `\input` macros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usual white space issues, add `%` to hide the end of line space

```
\input{dummygraphic}%


\input{dummygraphic}%


\input{dummygraphic}%
```

there is a space token in addition to the graphic in each paragraph, normally that's reasonably harmless but as you get close to text width it causes a two-line paragraph with the graphic on one line and a space on the next, and you can not fit three such paragraphs on a page.

Comment: I understand this space can be seen between ``...\end{picture}Sometext`` such that the S of Sometext doesn't touch the frame of the picture.

Comment: @HorstGrünbusch there is one space after `\end{picture}` and one after `\input{...}` the `\par` at the end of a paragraph removes exact;y one glue at the end of the line, so you need to remove the one I commented out or the one in the input file after `{picture}`